# React Router + Redux + Transition group doesn't trigger special lifecycle hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I am using React Router + Redux and when I try to load a nested view(the nested views are inside a ReactTransitionGroup), it loads correctly but it doesn't fire any of the special hooks like 'ComponentWillEnter' or 'ComponentWillLeave'.

Before adding the Redux 'connects' it worked right.

My routes are something like this

```
<Route path="lists" component={Lists}>
        <Route path="listsA" component={ListsA}/>
        <Route path="listsB" component={ListsB}/>
 </Route>
```

My components

Lists

```
@connect(..)
class Lists extends React.Component {
     ...
     render(){
        const { pathname } = this.props.location;
        const key = pathname.split('/') || 'Lists';
        const element = this.props.children || <div/>;
        const messages = this.props.messages;
        const elementToAnimate = React.cloneElement(element, { key, messages });

        return <div className="lists-wrapper">
            <div className="nested-views">
                <ReactTransitionGroup>
                    {elementToAnimate}
                </ReactTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
}
```

ListsA/ListsB

```
@connect(..)
    class ListsA extends React.Component {
         ...
         render(){
            ...
          }
    }
```

I didn't write too much  code because I am not sure where the problem could be, if you need me to add more code I totally will.

Answer (score 0):

So I was going through this problem too last night and here's what I found out to make it work.

First there is this approach https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/101
Where you can wrap your connect component with a wrapper that handles the special lifecycle functions and pass props to your connect component.

Or

you can pass 'withRef' flag to connect and call those lifecycle functions from the connect component, and subsequently have that call your components lifecycle functions.
I wrapped this up into a package that you can just drop in front of connect.

```
// npm install --save connect-with-transition-group
// https://github.com/esayemm/connect-with-transition-group

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import connectWithTransitionGroup from 'connect-with-transition-group';

class Foo extends Component {
  // ...

  componentWillEnter(cb) {
    // this works!
    cb();
  }

  // ...
}

export default connectWithTransitionGroup(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  // IMPORTANT: must pass this flag to react-redux/connect
  {
    withRef: true,
  }
)(Foo));
```